# Wrapping content in anchor in two divs (including text node)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to wrap content within an `<a>` tag into two divs using JQuery.

For example, I have the following markup:

```html
<div class="column features">
  <div class="columnOne">

    <div class="column__item">
      <a href="#">
        Text 
        <span>Subtext</span>
        <img src="image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column__item">
      <a href="#">
        Text 
        <span>Subtext</span>
        <img src="image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```html
<div class="column features">
  <div class="columnOne">

    <div class="column__item">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="column__content">
          Text
          <span>Subtext</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column__image">
          <img src="image.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

However, with my current approach:

- `column__content` only renders once. I have multiple `column__item` divs on my page, but `column__content` only renders on the first `column__item` instance.
- ALL `span` tags from `column__item` get wrapped into that single `column__content` div.

Current JQuery:

```
$('.column.features .column__item a > img').wrapAll('<div class="column__image"></div>');
$('.column.features .column__item a > span').wrapAll('<div class="column__content"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.column__item a').each((i, e) => {
  const $link = $(e);
  
  $link.contents().wrapAll('<div class="column__content">');
  $link.append($('<div class="column__image">').append($link.find('img')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column features">
  <div class="columnOne">
    <div class="column__item">
      <a href="#">
        Text 
        <span>Subtext</span>
        <img src="image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column__item">
      <a href="#">
        Text 
        <span>Subtext</span>
        <img src="image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't get the wrapAll to work after filtering the image out.  It kept ignoring the text node.  So as a work around, I wrapped everything with the content div, and then made the image div and moved the image out of the content div into it.